# RoboSpice - difference between GsonObjectPersisterFactory and GsonRetrofitObjectPersisterFactory

Tags: android, json, caching, gson, robospice

I dont understand the difference between the two of those.

From what I understand:

1. Both of them save data on disc using Gson.
2. Both of them can handle any POJO object.

So what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The `GsonObjectPersisterFactory` is used in the [robospice-google-http-client](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Google-Http-Java-Client-module) and [robospice-spring-android](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Spring-Android-module) Robospice extensions.
The `GsonRetrofitObjectPersisterFactory` is used in the [robospice-retrofit](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Retrofit-module) extension.

The difference is in the `retrofit.converter.Converter` object passed as a constructor argument to the `GsonRetrofitObjectPersisterFactory`. This object basically acts as a bridge between Robospice and Retrofit in the caching part. A different Retrofit `Converter` is used for the different JSON mapping solutions used in the robospice-retrofit extension, therefore you have a `JacksonRetrofitObjectPersisterFactory` as well.

See [`com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.retrofit.RetrofitObjectPersisterFactory`](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/blob/release/extensions/robospice-retrofit-parent/robospice-retrofit/src/main/java/com/octo/android/robospice/persistence/retrofit/RetrofitObjectPersister.java) and [its package](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/tree/release/extensions/robospice-retrofit-parent/robospice-retrofit/src/main/java/com/octo/android/robospice/persistence/retrofit) for more info.